# Windows 11 Touchpad right-click

Tags: windows, windows-11, touchpad

There's an option in Control Panel "Press the lower left corner of the touchpad to right-click". Is there no "Press the lower right corner of the touchpad to right-click"?

My laptop is doing a right click when I press the bottom left corner of my touchpad. I am asking whether it's possible to do a right click when I press the bottom right corner of my touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which wasted a lot of time.  You need to find the "Mouse Properties -> Button Configuration" and unselect "Switch primary and secondary buttons".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).